# Fetch and Play back YouTube URL in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, youtube

I am working on one app where I am giving functionality to user to play Youtube video saved in database. And if user wants, he can update the video.

Say I have saved a link like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ziku4FLka4 in DB and I am playing the same link on a button click for which I have implemented code like below :

```
   UIWebView *wv;

strUTube = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ziku4FLka4";

        wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,viewBG.frame.size.width,viewBG.frame.size.height)];


    NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
    [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
    [html appendString:@"body {"];
    [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
    [html appendString:@"color: brown;"];
    [html appendString:@"}"];
    [html appendString:@"</style>"];
    [html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
    [html appendFormat:@"<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"", strUTube];

    [html appendFormat:@"width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>", viewBG.frame.size.width,viewBG.frame.size.height];
    [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    NSLog(@"html:%@",html);
    [wv loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [viewBG addSubview:wv];

    [self.view addSubview:viewBG];
```

Then on another button click, I am calling home page of Youtube and fetching the URL opened on a button click event with following code :

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];
NSLog(@"currentURL2 : %@",currentURL);
```

But the URL results into result like http://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=m-trends&v=to7uIG8KYhg which cannot be played later on.

I also tried to open the URL on my Mac Book but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple trick extract videoID from below currentURL:

```
    http://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=m-trends&v=to7uIG8KYhg
```

Now create new Youtube VideoURL like

```
  NSString *newVideoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",extractedVideoID];
```

Now play this newVideoURL in embedded player.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=to7uIG8KYhg

Answer (score 1):

First use new iFrame method to embed you tube videos. Below is a template url where you can fill up width, height, video id and isAutoplay from code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
</head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;" bgcolor="#000000">
        <iframe class="youtube-player" background-color:#000000 allowtransparency= "true" type="text/html" width=%f height=%f src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?fs=1&autoplay=%d&loop=%d&rel=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>

NSString   *youTubeHTMLTemplate = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path 
                                                         encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                            error: &error];
finalHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeHTMLTemplate, htmlFrameWidth, htmlFrameHeight, videoID, isAutoplay];
```

You can use built in NSString methods to easily extract video id from youtube video url.